# Adding public data to the JWT response with lexik

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently using Symfony 5 with lexik and when I to generate the JWT token, I would like for the response to get me the token and the username so I could have something like this:

```json
{
    "username":"username"
    "token": "token"
}
```

I tried of course to use the doc here : https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-data-customization.md#eventsauthentication_success---adding-public-data-to-the-jwt-response but whenever I test it in Postman, I still only get the token and I am completely stuck on what to do...

My EventListener:

```php
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Event\AuthenticationSuccessEvent;


class AuthenticationSuccessListener
{
    /**
     * @param AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccessResponse(AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $user = $event->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return;
        }

        $data['data'] = array(
            'username' => $user->getUsername(),
        );

        $event->setData($data);
    }
}
```

the service in services.yaml

```yaml
acme_api.event.authentication_success_listener:
        class: App\EventListener\AuthenticationSuccessListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success, method: onAuthenticationSuccessResponse }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In your services.yaml the event is called `lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success` instead of `lexik_jwt_authentication.on_authentication_success`. Is that intended? Are you sure your listener is being called? Try debugging with XDebug or using `dd()` to see if the code is actually being called. You can also check `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher`

Comment: @dbrumann
Oh yeah my bad `lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success`, it was my last test before posting here and I forgot to remove it.
As for the debug, I tried with bin/console and it seems to be called. The result "lexik_jwt_authentication.authentication_success" is : Order: #1      Callable: `App\EventListener\AuthenticationSuccessListener::onAuthenticationSuccessResponse()`   Priority: 0 (hope it's clear enough, tried my best with the syntax of stackoverflow lmao)

Comment: Try to add the user interface use inside your Listener it might be that you are not getting throw your if statment because of this:
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
because i am working with a new project now its exactly the same as yours  and with more than the token in the response you can check the code here if you want:
https://github.com/amhanna86/backend

Comment: @AliMhanna
Oh. My. Lord. I can't believe the solution was that easy but yeah it works now! Thank you so, so much, I was stuck for way too long on this!

Comment: No worries i am gald being able to help

Comment: @Drozap i hope its okay for you i added my comment as an answer i would really appriciate it if you accept it as the right answer

Comment: @AliMhanna
No problem! And hey, it could help other people with a similar issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add the user interface use inside your Listener it might be that you are not getting throw your if statment because of this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
```